# Upload Files from web url using Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, upload, cfhttp, cffile

I have been allowing user to upload file via a form online like this:

```
<form action="upload.htm" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="upload_form" method="post">
<input type="file" name="upfile">
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload Photos">
</form>
```

Then on the back end the cffile would upload the file:

```
<cffile action="upload" destination="#currentpath#" accept="image/jpeg, image/gif, image/png" fileField="form.upfile" nameconflict="makeunique">
```

Now I want to do automation so that the image file does not have to be sitting in the user's computer but rather from a web destination e.g. http://www.sample.com/images/myimage.jpg instead of c:/images/myimage.jpg

I have tried this:

```
<cfhttp method="get" url="http://www.example.com/images/myimage.jpg"  resolveurl="Yes" throwOnError="Yes">
<cfif cfhttp.mimeType eq "image/jpeg">
    <cfset currentpath = expandpath('/test/')>
    <cffile action="upload" destination="#currentpath#" accept="image/jpeg, image/gif, image/png" fileField="#cfhttp.fileContent#" nameconflict="makeunique">
</cfif>
```

However, it is giving me an error:

> Invalid content type: ''. The files upload action requires forms to
>   use enctype="multipart/form-data"

I am not using a form to upload but it seems to require a form field.

So I tried this:

```
<cfhttp method="get" url="http://www.example.com/images/myimage.jpg"  resolveurl="Yes" throwOnError="Yes">
<cfif cfhttp.mimeType eq "image/jpeg">
    <cfset currentpath = expandpath('/test/')>
    <cffile action="write" output="#cfhttp.fileContent#"  file="#currentpath#/someimage.jpg">
</cfif>
```

This one writes out a "file" called someimage.jpg but the output is NOT a jpg file, but something unrecognizable.  With the cffile "write", it doesn't allow to check for image type or same file name.

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: *I am not using a form to upload but it seems to require a form field.* Yes, an "upload" would require a form field, but .. that is not what the code is doing. An upload transfers a file from a client machine to the CF server. The cfhttp call is server-to-server. In this case it downloads a file from a remote onto the CF Server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the call was successful, the current code may be retrieving and/or saving the response as text, instead of binary, which would corrupt the image. To ensure you get back a binary image, use `getAsBinary="yes"`.

Having said that, it is simpler to save the response to a file directly within the [cfhttp](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ffc.html) call:

```
<cfhttp url="http://www.example.com/images/myimage.jpg" 
    method="get" 
    getAsBinary="yes"
    path="#currentpath#" 
    file="someimage.jpg"
    resolveurl="Yes" 
    throwOnError="Yes" />
```

Comment: Thank you!  This works in retrieving the file.  But how can I be sure that the user input URL contains an image file?  I also need to ensure the output file name is the same as input file name. Any way to get the file name from cfhttp?

Comment: That would be a different question.  This one has been answered.

Comment: @DanBracuk The question was for retrieving image file in particular from the web. That's why in the original code there is a check for image file, then a file write. If you know the answer I would appreciated if you can let me know.

Comment: @Jack - Yes, but the main question was why is not the image saving correctly. The answer is, ensure image is saved as binary not text. The question of how to verify a URL exists and validate a specific content type is a separate topic. Having said that, did you try adding `getAsBinary="yes"` to your code? That may be all you need. If not, you should open a separate thread about how to validate the url and type. That will make the thread easier to find for the next guy that runs into that issue.

Comment: @Leigh Just setting getAsBinary="yes" does not ensure only image is downloaded.  I can load a pdf with it also.  I think I will have to do a isimagefile check after loading it on server.

Comment: *does not ensure only image is downloaded* It is not supposed to. I think you misunderstood the latter suggestion. I meant "just add it to your *original* code".